# Can't change text size programmatically when using autosizing

Tags: android, textview, android-textview-autosize

I have multiple TextViews that use `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` and what I want to do is check which of those have the smallest text size after auto resize and then set that size to all other TextViews.

So I have method like this called from `onCreate()`

```
private fun setLabelsFontSize(){
    rootView.post {
        val minTextSize = minOf(textView1.textSize, textView2.textSize, textView3.textSize)

        textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, minTextSize)
        textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, minTextSize)
        textView3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, minTextSize)
    }
}
```

But nothing happens, text size stays the same. When I remove `app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` from layout file then it works fine. How can I fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call setTexSize like this:

```
private fun setLabelsFontSize(){
    rootView.post {
        val minTextSize = minOf(textView1.textSize, textView2.textSize, textView3.textSize)
        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView1, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_NONE)
        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView2, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_NONE)
        TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(textView3, TextViewCompat.AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_NONE)
        textView1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, minTextSize)
        textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, minTextSize)
        textView3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, minTextSize)
    }
}
```